# Find the area of the trapezoid $ABCD$

Tags: geometry

Given:
$AB||DC$, $AB=7$ $cm$, $AD=BC=5$ $cm$ and the distance between $AB$ and $DC$ is $4$ $cm$.

Find the area of trapezoid $ABCD$.

WHAT I TRIED:

Since $AB||DC$ and $AL=BM=4$ $cm$, the figure must be a parallelogram.

$\therefore$ $AB=LM=7$ $cm$

I do not know what to do further.

[image]

Comment: $3^2+4^2 = 5^2$

Comment: How? Can you explain?

Comment: Try to find the length of DL and MC by Pythagoras, and you will stumble upon this equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

== Show $\;\Delta ADL\cong\Delta BCM\;$ ,and thus $\;DL=MC\;$

== Use Pythagoras Theorem to find $\;DL=MC\;$

Finally, use the formula

$$S_{ABCD}=\frac12\left(AB+CD\right)h$$

Comment: How will I show $\triangle$ADL$=$$\triangle$BCM

Comment: @Abhishekstudent, SSA, since in a straight angle triangle if we know two sides we also know the third one, and we know one angle...

Comment: Thanks! I found that even if I don't prove that the two triangles are equal, the also I can find the answer by using Pythagoras theorem. Thanks for your precious time.